# search a word in a string for exact match / even startingwith the word is not working

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a id and a text field.

I need to search a word with exact match or starting with the word in a string with single mysql query.

E.g `select * from tablename where textfield like "%cam%.`
This will return all the text id which cam is found anywhere in the single .

but i need to get the result that can be queried by splitting single words in a sentence.

id text

```
1 Camel_walk.
2 camel does drink water.
3 does Camel_store water.
4 In deset people can find_camel
5 this will not return
```

when i query for
`select * from tablename where textfield like "%camel%.`
return first 1,2,3,4

but i need to get the id in which the word start with camel

```
1)select * from tablename where textfield like "Camel%"
return 1,3 ( which is not working for me)
or even
2)select * from tablename where textfield like "%Camel"
return 4
```

These two queries is not working
Can some one help

Thanks

Comment: `select id from tablename where text like "%Camel%"` will return 1,3. usage of proper(or camel) case with like operator makes the search case-sensitive. consistent case will keep the query case-insensitive.

Comment: `select id from tablename where text like "%camel"` will return 4. see the difference in the case of string. `select id from tablename where text like "%camel%"` will return 1,2,3,4. `select id from tablename where text like "Camel%"` will return 1. `select id from tablename where text like "camel%"` will return 1,2. `select id from tablename where text like "camel %"` will return 2.

Comment: This is basic SQL. Not even a slightly complex SQL statement(s). I wonder why would you be looking for a solid SQL query if you are using a framework like cakephp? IMHO, using hard coded SQL in cake is not wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tablename where textfield like "Camel%" or textfield like ' %Camel'
```

Notice the space before `%` in second condition. These two conditions will match when any word starts with `Camel` in your string, doesn't matter if it is the first word or not.

Comment: I'd only select id instead of *

Comment: I thought that use of proper/camel case in like query will not return all the results. At least, it never worked for me. ... like %Camel%... will look for entries containing "Camel" and not "camel" or "CAMEL" or "cAmeL".

Comment: For example, searching for "test" will return test', "tests", "tested", and "testing" that is good but i dont want "fastest" etc any more

Comment: Then put a space before the closing `%` as well

Comment: if i search for test and result "sunat latest post" would not be there...but it comes if i use space before % please suugest

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what output is required in the question. In comments fixing for things one by one gets things out of track

Answer (score 2):

When you use a camel(proper) case in the SQL like query, the string will find case-sensitive match of the string, however, "camel" and "CAMEL" will look for camel/CAMEL/Camel...so on (case-insensitive match)

`select id from tablename where text like "%Camel%"` will return 1,3.

`select id from tablename where text like "%camel"` will return 4.

`select id from tablename where text like "%camel%"` will return 1,2,3,4.

`select id from tablename where text like "Camel%"` will return 1.

`select id from tablename where text like "camel%"` will return 1,2.

`select id from tablename where text like "camel %"` (space between "camel" and "%") will return 2.

Notice the difference in the case of the string.

Comment: `select id from tablename where text like "%camel_%" OR text like 'camel%'`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all cases

```
SELECT id
  from tablename
 WHERE textfield like '%[^A-z^0-9]Camel%' -- In the middle of a sentence
    OR textfield like 'Camel%'            -- At the beginning of a sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

user match against

$conditions[]=array("MATCH(MODEL_name.fieldname) AGAINST('$text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" );